# android button position not working for me

Tags: android, button, position

I'm trying to get the position of the buttons.
but I get 0.0 as the position.

I was guessing that once I have created the Button instances, and referenced them to the buttons previously positioned in xml all around the screen, then I would get the absolute position of the buttons..... not the case.....

.... what am I doing wrong, please????

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

```
private static final int[] idArray = {R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6,
        R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.button10, R.id.button11, R.id.button12,
        R.id.button13, R.id.button14, R.id.button15, R.id.button16, R.id.button17, R.id.button18,
        R.id.button19, R.id.button20
};

final Button[] button = new Button[idArray.length];
final Rect[] myRect = new Rect[idArray.length];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    for (int t = 1; t < idArray.length; t++) {

        button[t] = (Button) findViewById(idArray[t]);

        Log.d("", "left of button" +button[t].getX());


        myRect[t] = new Rect();
        myRect[t].set((int)button[t].getX(), (int)button[t].getY(), button[t].getRight(), button[t].getBottom());
        Log.d("", "" + myRect[t]);
    }

}
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Your view (Button) is not a part of layout yet.
get location when ready:

```
button[t].post(new Runnable() {
    Log.d("", "left of button" +button[t].getX());
});
```